# How read big text file and work with it in Java

Tags: java, file

I have a large text file, and i want read it, when i try do it without any operations like add some text from this file to List it read file maximum to one minute but when i try add some text to arrayList and next i want do some operations it is too slowly, do you know how can i read this data and use it? 
This is my code:

```
public class ReaderTEst {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    List<String> graphList = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> edgeList = new ArrayList<>();
    FileInputStream inputStream = null;
    Scanner sc = null;
    try {
        inputStream = new FileInputStream("myText.txt");
        sc = new Scanner(inputStream, "UTF-8");
        while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = sc.nextLine();
            line = line.replace("\uFEFF", "");//i use UTF-8 file so I need delete unneeded character
            if (Character.isWhitespace(line.charAt(0))) {
                edgeList.add(line.trim());
            } else {
                graphList.add(line);
            }
        }
        if (sc.ioException() != null) {
            throw sc.ioException();
        }
    } finally {
        if (inputStream != null) {
            inputStream.close();
        }
        if (sc != null) {
            sc.close();
        }
    }
}
```

}
It takes to many time, do you know how it could be faster? I have file txt with 600 MB
When i change :

```
List<Integer> graphList = new ArrayList<>(1);
int i = 0;
while (sc.hasNextLine()) {`String line = sc.nextLine();`
        line = line.replace("\uFEFF", "");//i use UTF-8 file so I need delete unneeded character

            graphList.add(i++);

    }
```

i works, but when i want put string it takes too long time

Answer (score 1):

You should use `BufferedReader.readLine()`. You can read millions of lines per second with that. `Scanner` is overkill for what you're doing.

BUT `\uFEFF` is not text. Is this *really* a text file? Is that a BOM marker? in which case it will only be at the beginning of the first line: no need to scan for it in every line.

Comment: It is sine i use UTF-8 and in first character i have strange empty character, so i try to use it only at charAt(0)

Comment: So it *is* a BOM marker, so you should remove it from the first line only.

Answer (score 0):

Your main issues are the following:

```
List<String> graphList = new ArrayList<>();
List<String> edgeList = new ArrayList<>();
```

You should initialize each `List` with an initial capacity so that the JVM does not need to automatically expand the backing array.

```
line = line.replace("\uFEFF", "");
```

This will also slow down your program.  How often is `\uFEFF` in each line?  I would check if the line contains `\uFEFF` before attempting to replace it.

Other than that, there's not much else to optimize; maybe you can utilize a `FileChannel` to read the file, but that's about it.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I advise to use the LinkedList realization of List because of architectual features. Thus the ArrayList is built-on arrays, the LinkedList consists on Nodes. The ArrayList creates new bigger arrays and copy old one the new one, then it is reach some capasity. Oracle has perfect documentation about this, I recommend it to you [LinkedList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html)
[ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)